# What does this statement do on Linux?

Tags: linux, command-prompt

I am trying to complete a lab report and I have just started using linux. I am really new to this ecosystem and I don't know how most of it works. I'm slowly learning from the labscript how to compile and execute C programs. However, after executing this statement

> execute the output binary file using: `$ ./myapp I am a student taking CMP 310`

I lost the "$" sign and whenever I pressed enter this ">" would be printed before any statement and I couldn't execute or exit. If any of you could kindly explain what I did I would really appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: That's the secondary prompt. You get it when the shell expects you to provide more input. Pressing Ctrl+C (bash's "cancel") will give your a fresh start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have pasted an unmatched quote symbol, `'` or `"` or a backtick ` and your terminal allows you to enter multiline statement and waits until you close the quote or backtick to evaluate it. To exit the multiline mode, either enter the closing character, or hit Ctrl-C, which in this case interrupts the input.

You have to paste only this part:

```
./myapp I am a student taking CMP 310
```

It tries to execute `myapp` executable file in your working directory (which `./` stands for), passing to it arguments `I am a student taking CMP 310`.

**Me reproducing your problem:**

```
16:45 $ "I have no idea what I am doing
> wut
> 
> 
> hello?
>
```

Comment: It is because of ". Just close them ;)

Comment: Are you talking about the "I have no idea what I am doing" part? I got myself into that situation on purpose, in order to show how one can get in such an awkward position and how one will potentially behave, anxious, frightened and disoriented. Sorry if I made you worry about me, it was merely a dramatization, staged by a man of high competence.

Comment: It was a joke. I don't think his problem is because of quotes. May be myapp has its own prompt.

Comment: I don't think a prompt with ">" is something you can implement by accident in a C program, so it's most likely shell's secondary prompt. Your answer is not wrong, ^C indeed can help OP escape his situation. I just tried to explain how he/she got there.

Comment: Thank you very much my fellow programmers!

Answer (score 1):

Most probably Ctrl+C will help you.
If you are working in GUI mode (not terminal) you can just close the window and open new shell session in new window.